# On the Spring MVC Showcase, how do the Standard Resolvable Web Arguments work

Tags: spring-mvc

With a working and running instance of [Spring MVC Showcase](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mvc-showcase). How is this handled http://localhost:8080/spring-mvc-showcase**/data/standard/request** which provides the response of:

> request = Request(GET //localhost:8080/spring-mvc-showcase/data/standard/request)@6b70f599, userPrincipal = null, requestLocale = en_US

There is no direct mapping for a data/standard/request in the [RequestDataController.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mvc-showcase/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/mvc/data/RequestDataController.java)

With this standard one I am presuming that there is something built into Spring that is handling and providing that response? Maybe with the "@RequestMapping("/data")"

I am not really finding anything in the documentation that says if you do this then Spring handles any */standard/request with the above response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping for /data/standard/request is in `https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mvc-showcase/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/mvc/data/standard/StandardArgumentsController.java`